# How to set max date in jquery.dateselect.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

Download plugin link

http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Nice-Scrollable-Date-Selector-Plugin-With-jQuery-DateSelect.html

**jQuery DateSelect**

There are a lot of date pickers out there, but why have an old and boring calendar when you can have a modern and slick date selector?

Meet DateSelect, a new way to select dates on your forms.`enter code here`

**Installing**

Just grab the JS and CSS files, include them on your HTML file and you're set.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dateselect.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dateselect.js"></script>
```

**Automatic mode**

In automatic mode you'll just have to add a data-* attribute and the plugin will do all thee work (but for this to work, you must have also a valid HTML 5 DOCTYPE).

If you can't (or don't want to) add a DOCTYPE you can still use the good old $('#input').dateSelect() to bind your input fields.

**HTML**

Manual mode

In manual mode, you'll have to call the $.dateSelect.show() method to open the date picker.

**JS**

```
$('.btn-date').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.dateSelect.show({
        element: 'input[name="date2"]'
    });
});
```